# How to add custom posts to pages via a select box

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add an editable text area to the sidebar of my pages and to be able to show different text in this sidebar for different pages. For a variety of reasons, I don't want to use a plugin.
The solution I have come up with so far is to create a custom post which will contain the sidebar text:

```
add_action( 'init', 'left_column_posts' );

function left_column_posts() {
    register_post_type( 'left_column_text', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Left Column Posts' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Left Column Text' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

So far so good.
The next step is to be able to select one of these posts and add it to the page:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'init_left_column_text_selection');

function init_left_column_text_selection(){
  add_meta_box("left-column-text-meta", "Left Column Text", "add_left_column_text", "page", "side", "low");
}

function add_left_column_text(){
  global $post;  
  echo '<label>Left Column:</label>';
  echo '<select>';
  echo '<option value="" selected>= = = = = = = = = = </option>';
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'left_column_text'));
    if($loop->have_posts()) {
    //  while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    //    $title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'title', true );    
    //    echo '<option value="'.get_the_ID().'">';     
     //   echo $title;
    //  echo the_title();
    //  echo '</option>';
    //  endwhile;
    }   
    echo '</select>';
    wp_reset_query();
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_left_column_text');

function save_left_column_text(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "$left_column_text", $_POST["$left_column_text"]);
}
```

This is where I've got stuck. The commented lines are the part not working. How do I get the post ID and save it? Also, the other problem is that when I save the page, the slug is being over-written with the post content - so I suspect there is something here I'm failing to grasp.

The final stage is to create a widget which I can then add to the sidebar and which will retrieve the custom post on a per page basis.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Trying to understand...So does this value vary on a post-by-post basis?

Comment: mevius - perhaps I should have mentioned, I'm using wordpress as a CMS rather than as a blog, so essentially I'm working with pages rather than with posts. I'm just trying to add a bit more 'granularity' to the pages - and for which I have gone down the line of using "custom posts".

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've come up with a working solution, so I'll post my code in the hope it might help someone else who is looking for a similar solution. The code above was along the right lines, but contained a couple of typos (duh!) which stopped it saving the select value. Also, I found that changing the position to "advanced" in the add_meta_box() resolved the problem of the page slug being overwritten (but not sure why). I'll post the complete code (to go in functions.php) below:

```
add_action( 'init', 'left_column_posts' );

function left_column_posts() {
    register_post_type( 'left_column_text', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Left Column Posts' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Left Column Text' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
        )
    );
}


add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'init_left_column_text_selection');

function init_left_column_text_selection(){
//add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $context, $priority ); 
  add_meta_box("left_column_text-meta", "Left Column Text", "add_left_column_text", "page", "advanced", "low");
}

function add_left_column_text(){
    global $post;
    $l_c_t = 0;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    if(isset($custom["left_column_text"])){
      $l_c_t = $custom["left_column_text"][0];
    }

    echo '<label>Left Column:</label>';
    echo '<select name="left_column_text">';
    echo '<option value="">= = = = = = = = = = </option>';
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'left_column_text',
      'nopaging'  => true
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);   
    if($query->have_posts()) {
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        echo '<option value="'.get_the_ID().'"';
        if($l_c_t == get_the_ID()){
            echo 'selected';
        }
        echo '>';
        the_title();            
        echo '</option>';
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_query();
    }       
    echo '</select>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_left_column_text');

function save_left_column_text(){
  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "left_column_text", $_POST["left_column_text"]);
}
```

The code to go in the widget is very simple. It simply looks to see if there is a "left_column_text" attribute to the page and if so, it finds the corresponding post:

```
// WIDGET CODE GOES HERE    
$custom = get_post_custom();
$left_column_id = 0;
if(isset($custom['left_column_text'])) {
    $left_column_id = $custom['left_column_text'][0];
}

$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'left_column_text'));
if($loop->have_posts()) {
  while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();       
    if ($left_column_id == get_the_ID()){
        echo the_content();
    }       
  endwhile;
}   
wp_reset_query();
```

This just goes inside a normal widget.

So, with this, you can create separate text areas (I've called them "left column posts") and select from these posts to add them to your page. Using your widgets you can then choose where to display them on your page. I don't think it would be hugely scalable (ie no good for dozens of custom posts), but I think it's definitely more scalable than adding dozens of custom text widgets to your pages.

Hope it's useful to somebody.